# Complex(?) Access Control

Tags: c#, access-control

I have what I think might be a relatively complex access control situation (not having much experience, I could be completely wrong). This system is a private/in-house desktop only application if that makes any difference.

The system I am working on tracks **Certificates** for **Personnel** (using **bold** for tables). Only certain **Users** have access to this system, making it somewhat controlled, but further control is necessary. For instance; Not all **Users** should be able to access **Certificates** for **Personnel** that are Management, this should really be restricted to HR only. Additionally, it may be the case where certain **Users** can access any **Personnel** but only certain **Certificates**.

Current thoughts are to add a field to **Certificates** & **Personnel** that is an int with the permission/access level. Similar to [this](http://codeingenious.blogspot.co.nz/2011/04/flagged-enum-in-sql-server.html?_sm_au_=iHVs6jH2n0mmV6r6) setup. The **User** table would then also have an "AccessLevel" field so that a comparison can be made.

Not sure on the amount of access levels, currently thinking of the following;

```
[Flags]
public enum AccessLevel
{
    None,
    ReadOnly,
    Normal, // Can view all Certificates and Personnel that aren't set to Management
    Management, // For "sensitive" Personnel and/or Certificates
    HR, // Full access
    Admin // Permission control/editing
}
```

Having not done Access Control to this level of complexity before though, **I'm not certain if I'm heading in the right direction or not?**

Comment: Might hierarchy play a role, e.g. if you have a tree of employees would you want managers to be able to see the certificates of their direct reports?

Comment: That's technically correct. It doesn't really boil down to that level of hierarchy though; HR are mostly in charge of managing everyone's certificates. That said, Personnel Logistics are the ones that need access to certain certificates as they are the ones who liaise with the clients (but they don't need access to say, CVs - which HR would like to track using the system), i.e. this person meets the requirements, as evidenced by these certificates.

Comment: For simple systems I've generally used a table of `Privileges` (`PrivilegeId`, `Name`, `ShortName` used in application code, `Description`) and a table of `UserPrivileges` to grant access and a table to control who can grant/revoke privileges, e.g. `UserAdministersPrivilege`. That avoids the bit fiddling, and possibility of running out of bits, that bitmasks provide. I've done a number of systems with hierarchies several levels deep with implicit (A user can always see documents for their branch/division/company by default.) and explicit access for privileges at various levels.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid writing the authorization logic in code. Instead you should try to externalize your authorization. Use [XACML](http://developers.axiomatics.com/blog/index/entry/xacml-reference-architecture.html), the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language. XACML gives you an extensible architecture, a policy language rich enough to cater for your authorization use case (and more), as well as more advanced ones.

With XACML, you can write rules about the different actions (view, edit, control...) and you can choose which parameters / attributes matter to you. For instance  you could write:

- a user can edit the document if and only if the user.id == document.owner.id
- a user can view a document if and only if the user.location == document.location

I recently gave a talk on externalizing authorization at the Cloud Identity Summit. You can find my slides [here](http://www.slideshare.net/DavidBrossard/json-rest-alfa-why-lasagna-is-better-than-spaghetti).

HTH,
David.

Comment: Seems like a nice system. I'm not sure it would work with the one I'm developing though; It is a C# WinForms Desktop application that communicates with an MSSQL database...So as far as I can tell, the rules either need to be hard-coded (definitely not the best option) or persisted in the database, as that's the only part that's centralised.

Comment: The rules in XACML are expressed as XACML. You then evaluate them using a PDP e.g. Balana (open source) or Axiomatics (vendor). You then use a PEP SDK to write your own client that will protect your app...

Comment: It has been sidelined for the time being. At present the developers happen to be the only ones who need access to the live data so there's no need for access control as yet. (I know it's probably harder to implement later, but it was the boss' decision, not mine...)

Comment: Actually, so long as you take a clean architecture / API-driven architecture based on standards then you can easily add in XACML later. Let me know when that happens.